# Get the distance between two geo points - offline map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

some applications using an offline map and them can get the distance between two geo points. like [Maps.ME](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps.pro&hl=en) application .

> Get instant access to detailed maps of all countries from anywhere in
>   the world! No internet connection is required.

Do they use Google map or using another map or custom map?

at this app I can specify two locations and it get me ~time/~distance between them locations.

How can use like this map as offline map ?

Answer (score 1):

Its using open street map.
Check out openstreetmap.org for more information.

Comment: Are u sure ? is it possible to use openstreetmap on android ?!

Comment: Yeah it says so in the manual of maps.me :-) another source is here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maps.Me